# Can't figure out OS Login IAM permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

Can someone please help me understand which IAM permission I am still missing?

I'm trying to enable [`OS Login`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin) on a single Compute VM, and have added `enable-oslogin: TRUE`. When I SSH through the UI, I see this error message:

[image: Error]

[The instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin) say:

> roles/iam.serviceAccountUser

**AND**

> roles/compute.osLogin **OR** roles/compute.osAdminLogin

**My IAM permissions:**
[image: IAM permission]

Comment: Seems like everything is in order. Are you part of an organization? If so, you would need to add **compute.osLoginExternalUser**. If unsure about the organization, you can try to `gcloud compute ssh` to the VM. It will return this error:  <br/>`Insufficient IAM permissions. The instance belongs to an external organization. You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role on the external organization to configure POSIX account information.`

Answer (score 2):

What I can notice from the current roles you have in IAM is that the only role you should assign at IAM level is the ***roles/iam.serviceAccountUser***, other roles ***roles/compute.osLogin*** or ***roles/compute.osAdminLogin*** should be assigned at [instance level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58qD2.png), according to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users).

Comment: According to the link you gave, yes. But in practice if you assign `roles/compute.os(Admin)?Login` on an instance, it will [fail](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/902766efd755a21c6dba898d05a021d1). Technically, `roles/compute.os(Admin)?Login` include `compute.projects.get` but it's needed for a project.